# Visual Studio 2013 com problema

Tags: visual-studio

A um bom tempo venho programando para WP8.1, para fins acadêmicos. E a um tempo atrás, o VS parou de exibir a preview da UI, então nem consigo visualizar botões, textbox, e afins. Como resolvo isso? Já tentei reparar, já desinstalei tudo, e nada funciona.

PS.: Quando faço aplicações Windows, tudo aparece normalmente.

Comment: Já tentou resetar as configurações ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Cara, vê se está havendo algum estouro de memória, o emulador WP8.1 usa muita memória..

Comment: Tentei sim Paulo, mas sem efeito. Continua a mesma coisa, sem mostrar nada. :/

Comment: Não é na parte do emulador, mas do preview da UI caro Samuel, não aparece nada.